# Send gmail on button click without using intent

Tags: java, android

protected void sendEmail(String bookName, String writer, String publisher ,String description ) {
        Log.i("Send email", "");

```
    String TO = "zxcvbnmnbvcx@gmail.com";
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Book name : "+ bookName +"\n"+"Writer : " + writer +"\n"+"Publisher : "+publisher +"\n"+"Description : " +description +"\n");

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the error you are running into? Or provide more details on what exactly the problem is.

Comment: i have a fragment in which i have 4 edittext and i want to send exittext data to xyz@gmail.com on button click without open gmail compose

Comment: Please press the 'edit' button under your post and add it underneath your code

Comment: This sounds like something that malware might do, and so if I were writing the Gmail app I would want to prevent other programmers from being able to do this.

Comment: thanks i got the answer

Comment: If you have got the answer. Kindly add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create provider:

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Use GMailSender class to send mail (**Make sure, your GMail smtp account is open to another application**)

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);

            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0) {
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            }
            else {
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            }

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
GmailSender gs = new GmailSender("example@gmail.com", "yourPassword");
gs.sendMail("Subject", "Email body", "sender@gmail.com", "recipient@gmail.com"
```